# Complex power series which converges absolutely on the boundary converges absolutely on a neighborhood of the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

If a complex power series $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ converges absolutely for $|z| \leq 1$, does it necessarily converge absolutely for $|z| < 1 + \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Examples, *examples*... which examples did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false. For instance, $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$ has ray of convergence $1$, but it does converge absolutely $\forall|z|\leq1$.